# Unable to retrieve firebase data to Listview

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve data from my real-time firebase into a listview.

The Firebase Json Tree:
[image]

I want to retrieve Item, Expiry Date and Quantity in the listview format.

My code is as follows:

```
var lists = [];
 final database = FirebaseDatabase(
      databaseURL: "https://trackkit-a5cf3-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app")
      .reference()
      .child('Location 1');

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      body: Container(
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: database.onValue,
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Event> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.hasError &&
                snapshot.data!.snapshot.value != null) {
              print("Error on the way");
              lists.clear();
              DataSnapshot dataValues = snapshot.data!.snapshot;
              Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = dataValues.value;
              values.forEach((key, values) {
                lists.add(values);
              });
              return  ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: lists.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Card(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text("Item: " + lists[index]["Item"]),
                        Text("Expiry Date: " + lists[index]["Expiry Date"]),
                        Text("Quantity: " + lists[index]["Quantity"]),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            }
            return Container(child: Text("Add Items"));
          },
        ),
      ),

    );
  }
```

The current screen shows :
type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'

I have been trying for days! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are getting a Integer value in return to your `lists[index]["Quantity"]`. And you cannot concat and integer with String without converting into a String.

So Please use method `toString()` with `lists[index]["Quantity"]` to make it work properly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to `Quantity` make a String value, use `toString()` method on it in Text Widget,
like that: `Text("Quantity: " + lists[index]["Quantity"].toString())`